# Conditional expectation uniformly distributed random variables

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I am calculating the covariance of $X$ and $Y$, given that $X+Y>100$, but I am stuck calculating this expected value:

> $E[XY|X+Y>100]$

where $X$ and $Y$ are independent uniformly distributed random variables between $0$ and $100$, I need help on how to proceed with this calculation.

Comment: The conditional expectation equals $E[XYI(X+Y>100)]/P(X+Y>100)$, where $I()$ is an indicator variable.

Comment: It seems correct, thank you very much.